# IdentityServer3 and external login through OpenIDConnect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver3, openid-connect

In ASP.NET MVC app, I am trying to implement authentication against external OIDC service. For my testing I am using **IdentityServer3** (https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/) and **public OIDC demo server: https://mitreid.org/**

I cloned this sample from GitHub: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication

Then added the following code to register the public OIDC server as external login provider:

```
private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
{
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "<AuthTypeName>",
            Authority = "https://mitreid.org/",
            Caption = "MIT Test Server",
            ClientId = "<Client Id>",
            ClientSecret = "<Client Secret>",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44319/", //NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE
            ResponseType = "code",
            Scope = "openid email profile",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
        });
}
```

The code works, i get the option to login via external OIDC server. The browser redirects to the external server login page and when login and password is entered, the consent page is shown. However, after the browser navigates back to https://localhost:44319/ the user is not authenticated - `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false.

**Question:** What should be correct value of RedirectUri property? Does OpenIdConnect middleware have capability to parse the authantication info passed in from external server or it must be coded manually? Is there any sample code how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was studying the code and debugging quite a few hours (I am new to this) and I learned that:

- This problem is related to OpenIdConnect OWIN Middleware implemented by Microsoft (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect).
- The middleware from Microsoft expect that the OIDC server [sends the message using HTTP POST](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs#L195), but the MIT server does HTTP GET
- The middleware from Microsoft [expect that there is id token along with code in the message](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs#L258)  obtained from OIDC server, but the MIT server sends only the code.
- Looks like the RedirectUri can be any path under /identity because the middleware method AuthenticateCoreAsync() is hit on every request and it [does compare request path to configured Options.CallbackPath](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenidConnectAuthenticationHandler.cs#L187) (which is set from RedirectURI)

So I just had to implement the standard authorization code flow - exchange the code for id token, get claims, create authentication ticket and redirect to IdentityServer /identity/callback endpoint. When I've done this, everything started working. IdentityServer is awesome!

I inherited new set of classes from OpenIdConnect middleware and did override some methods. The key method is `async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()` in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler`. I pasted the code below in case it would help to someone.

```
public class CustomOidcHandler : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler
{
    private const string HandledResponse = "HandledResponse";

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private OpenIdConnectConfiguration _configuration;

    public CustomOidcHandler(ILogger logger) : base(logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked to process incoming authentication messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An <see cref="AuthenticationTicket"/> if successful.</returns>
    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        // Allow login to be constrained to a specific path. Need to make this runtime configurable.
        if (Options.CallbackPath.HasValue && Options.CallbackPath != (Request.PathBase + Request.Path))
            return null;

        OpenIdConnectMessage openIdConnectMessage = null;
        if (string.Equals(Request.Method, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            openIdConnectMessage = new OpenIdConnectMessage(Request.Query);

        if (openIdConnectMessage == null)
            return null;

        ExceptionDispatchInfo authFailedEx = null;
        try
        {
            return await CreateAuthenticationTicket(openIdConnectMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // We can't await inside a catch block, capture and handle outside.
            authFailedEx = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exception);
        }

        if (authFailedEx != null)
        {
            _logger.WriteError("Exception occurred while processing message: ", authFailedEx.SourceException);

            // Refresh the configuration for exceptions that may be caused by key rollovers. The user can also request a refresh in the notification.
            if (Options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound && authFailedEx.SourceException.GetType() == typeof(SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException))
                Options.ConfigurationManager.RequestRefresh();

            var authenticationFailedNotification = new AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>(Context, Options)
            {
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage,
                Exception = authFailedEx.SourceException
            };
            await Options.Notifications.AuthenticationFailed(authenticationFailedNotification).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (authenticationFailedNotification.HandledResponse)
                return GetHandledResponseTicket();

            if (authenticationFailedNotification.Skipped)
                return null;

            authFailedEx.Throw();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateAuthenticationTicket(OpenIdConnectMessage openIdConnectMessage)
    {
        var messageReceivedNotification =
            new MessageReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>(Context, Options)
            {
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage
            };
        await Options.Notifications.MessageReceived(messageReceivedNotification).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (messageReceivedNotification.HandledResponse)
        {
            return GetHandledResponseTicket();
        }
        if (messageReceivedNotification.Skipped)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // runtime always adds state, if we don't find it OR we failed to 'unprotect' it this is not a message we
        // should process.
        AuthenticationProperties properties = GetPropertiesFromState(openIdConnectMessage.State);
        if (properties == null)
        {
            _logger.WriteWarning("The state field is missing or invalid.");
            return null;
        }

        // devs will need to hook AuthenticationFailedNotification to avoid having 'raw' runtime errors displayed to users.
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(openIdConnectMessage.Error))
        {
            throw new OpenIdConnectProtocolException(
                string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    openIdConnectMessage.Error,
                    "Exception_OpenIdConnectMessageError", openIdConnectMessage.ErrorDescription ?? string.Empty,
                    openIdConnectMessage.ErrorUri ?? string.Empty));
        }


        // tokens.Item1 contains id token
        // tokens.Item2 contains access token
        Tuple<string, string> tokens = await GetTokens(openIdConnectMessage.Code, Options)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(openIdConnectMessage.IdToken))
            openIdConnectMessage.IdToken = tokens.Item1;

        var securityTokenReceivedNotification =
            new SecurityTokenReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>(Context,
                Options)
            {
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage,
            };
        await Options.Notifications.SecurityTokenReceived(securityTokenReceivedNotification).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (securityTokenReceivedNotification.HandledResponse)
            return GetHandledResponseTicket();

        if (securityTokenReceivedNotification.Skipped)
            return null;

        if (_configuration == null)
            _configuration = await Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(Context.Request.CallCancelled)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Copy and augment to avoid cross request race conditions for updated configurations.
        TokenValidationParameters tvp = Options.TokenValidationParameters.Clone();
        IEnumerable<string> issuers = new[] {_configuration.Issuer};
        tvp.ValidIssuers = tvp.ValidIssuers?.Concat(issuers) ?? issuers;
        tvp.IssuerSigningTokens = tvp.IssuerSigningTokens?.Concat(_configuration.SigningTokens) ?? _configuration.SigningTokens;

        SecurityToken validatedToken;
        ClaimsPrincipal principal =
            Options.SecurityTokenHandlers.ValidateToken(openIdConnectMessage.IdToken, tvp, out validatedToken);
        ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

        var claims = await GetClaims(tokens.Item2).ConfigureAwait(false);

        AddClaim(claims, claimsIdentity, "sub", ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, Options.AuthenticationType);
        AddClaim(claims, claimsIdentity, "given_name", ClaimTypes.GivenName);
        AddClaim(claims, claimsIdentity, "family_name", ClaimTypes.Surname);
        AddClaim(claims, claimsIdentity, "preferred_username", ClaimTypes.Name);
        AddClaim(claims, claimsIdentity, "email", ClaimTypes.Email);

        // claims principal could have changed claim values, use bits received on wire for validation.
        JwtSecurityToken jwt = validatedToken as JwtSecurityToken;
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, properties);

        if (Options.ProtocolValidator.RequireNonce)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(openIdConnectMessage.Nonce))
                openIdConnectMessage.Nonce = jwt.Payload.Nonce;

            // deletes the nonce cookie
            RetrieveNonce(openIdConnectMessage);
        }

        // remember 'session_state' and 'check_session_iframe'
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(openIdConnectMessage.SessionState))
            ticket.Properties.Dictionary[OpenIdConnectSessionProperties.SessionState] = openIdConnectMessage.SessionState;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_configuration.CheckSessionIframe))
            ticket.Properties.Dictionary[OpenIdConnectSessionProperties.CheckSessionIFrame] =
                _configuration.CheckSessionIframe;

        if (Options.UseTokenLifetime)
        {
            // Override any session persistence to match the token lifetime.
            DateTime issued = jwt.ValidFrom;
            if (issued != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = issued.ToUniversalTime();
            }
            DateTime expires = jwt.ValidTo;
            if (expires != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = expires.ToUniversalTime();
            }
            ticket.Properties.AllowRefresh = false;
        }

        var securityTokenValidatedNotification =
            new SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>(Context,
                Options)
            {
                AuthenticationTicket = ticket,
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage,
            };

        await Options.Notifications.SecurityTokenValidated(securityTokenValidatedNotification).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (securityTokenValidatedNotification.HandledResponse)
        {
            return GetHandledResponseTicket();
        }
        if (securityTokenValidatedNotification.Skipped)
        {
            return null;
        }
        // Flow possible changes
        ticket = securityTokenValidatedNotification.AuthenticationTicket;

        // there is no hash of the code (c_hash) in the jwt obtained from the server
        // I don't know how to perform the validation using ProtocolValidator without the hash
        // that is why the code below is commented
        //var protocolValidationContext = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext
        //{
        //    AuthorizationCode = openIdConnectMessage.Code,
        //    Nonce = nonce
        //};
        //Options.ProtocolValidator.Validate(jwt, protocolValidationContext);

        if (openIdConnectMessage.Code != null)
        {
            var authorizationCodeReceivedNotification = new AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification(Context, Options)
            {
                AuthenticationTicket = ticket,
                Code = openIdConnectMessage.Code,
                JwtSecurityToken = jwt,
                ProtocolMessage = openIdConnectMessage,
                RedirectUri =
                    ticket.Properties.Dictionary.ContainsKey(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.RedirectUriUsedForCodeKey)
                        ? ticket.Properties.Dictionary[OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.RedirectUriUsedForCodeKey]
                        : string.Empty,
            };
            await Options.Notifications.AuthorizationCodeReceived(authorizationCodeReceivedNotification)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (authorizationCodeReceivedNotification.HandledResponse)
            {
                return GetHandledResponseTicket();
            }
            if (authorizationCodeReceivedNotification.Skipped)
            {
                return null;
            }
            // Flow possible changes
            ticket = authorizationCodeReceivedNotification.AuthenticationTicket;
        }

        return ticket;
    }

    private static void AddClaim(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> claims, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity, string key, string claimType, string issuer = null)
    {
        string subject = claims
            .Where(it => it.Item1 == key)
            .Select(x => x.Item2).SingleOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subject))
            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(
                new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer));
    }


    private async Task<Tuple<string, string>> GetTokens(string authorizationCode, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        // exchange authorization code at authorization server for an access and refresh token
        Dictionary<string, string> post = null;
        post = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"client_id", options.ClientId},
            {"client_secret", options.ClientSecret},
            {"grant_type", "authorization_code"},
            {"code", authorizationCode},
            {"redirect_uri", options.RedirectUri}
        };

        string content;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var postContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(post);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(options.Authority.TrimEnd('/') + "/token", postContent)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        // received tokens from authorization server
        var json = JObject.Parse(content);
        var accessToken = json["access_token"].ToString();
        string idToken = null;
        if (json["id_token"] != null)
            idToken = json["id_token"].ToString();

        return new Tuple<string, string>(idToken, accessToken);
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>> GetClaims(string accessToken)
    {
        string userInfoEndpoint = Options.Authority.TrimEnd('/') + "/userinfo";
        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(new Uri(userInfoEndpoint), accessToken);
        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var claims = userInfoResponse.Claims;

        return claims;
    }

    private static AuthenticationTicket GetHandledResponseTicket()
    {
        return new AuthenticationTicket(null, new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { HandledResponse, "true" } }));
    }

    private AuthenticationProperties GetPropertiesFromState(string state)
    {
        // assume a well formed query string: <a=b&>OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationPropertiesKey=kasjd;fljasldkjflksdj<&c=d>
        int startIndex = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state) || (startIndex = state.IndexOf("OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties", StringComparison.Ordinal)) == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int authenticationIndex = startIndex + "OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties".Length;
        if (authenticationIndex == -1 || authenticationIndex == state.Length || state[authenticationIndex] != '=')
        {
            return null;
        }

        // scan rest of string looking for '&'
        authenticationIndex++;
        int endIndex = state.Substring(authenticationIndex, state.Length - authenticationIndex).IndexOf("&", StringComparison.Ordinal);

        // -1 => no other parameters are after the AuthenticationPropertiesKey
        if (endIndex == -1)
        {
            return Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(Uri.UnescapeDataString(state.Substring(authenticationIndex).Replace('+', ' ')));
        }
        else
        {
            return Options.StateDataFormat.Unprotect(Uri.UnescapeDataString(state.Substring(authenticationIndex, endIndex).Replace('+', ' ')));
        }
    }
}


public static class CustomOidcAuthenticationExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the <see cref="OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware"/> into the OWIN runtime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IAppBuilder"/> passed to the configuration method</param>
    /// <param name="openIdConnectOptions">A <see cref="OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions"/> contains settings for obtaining identities using the OpenIdConnect protocol.</param>
    /// <returns>The updated <see cref="IAppBuilder"/></returns>
    public static IAppBuilder UseCustomOidcAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions openIdConnectOptions)
    {
        if (app == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));

        if (openIdConnectOptions == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(openIdConnectOptions));

        return app.Use(typeof(CustomOidcMiddleware), app, openIdConnectOptions);
    }
}
```

and in Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
....
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ....

     private void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)
    {
        app.UseCustomOidcAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "<name>",
                Authority = "<OIDC server url>",
                Caption = "<caption>",
                ClientId = "<client id>",
                ClientSecret = "<client secret>",
                // might be https://localhost:44319/identity/<anything>
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44319/identity/signin-customoidc",
                ResponseType = "code",
                Scope = "openid email profile address phone",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType
            }                
        );
    }
    ....
}
....
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly (after some simple modifications) to use AWS Cognito as an external IdP. The approach in [issue #2904](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2904) had failed completely. Thanks!

Comment: @spatialguy: Thanks for your post. Do you have this on github or the like?

Comment: @spatialguy: I guess you don't remember what tag or commit in `AspNetKatana` you applied your changes to?

Comment: For Authorization Code flow, I wonder if you can avoid the need to customise the OIDC middleware in this way by:

(1) Using the `MessageReceived` notification to exchange code for tokens, & populating the id token into `ProtocolMessage`; 

(2) Providing a custom `OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator` subclass that skips verification of `c_hash` if it's absent.

Comment: If the external IdP supports Hybrid Flow then the OWIN OIDC middleware should work out of the box if `response_type` contains `id_token`.